# .htaccess URL reroute to different folder based on first part of query

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Here is my .htaccess now

```
rewriteengine on
rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$ [OR]
rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$
rewriterule ^index.php/? "http\:\/\/example\.com\/" [R=301,L] #4a397bb852bc9
```

Which sends all requests from the root directory to index.php
What I need to do is send all requests from www.example.com/site2/ to www.example.com/site2/index.php

My understanding of regex has always stopped short of these curious rules and conds

Thanks, Joe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rule you named redirects any request, that’s URL path starts with `index.php` followed by an optional slash and that’s host name is either `www.example.com` or `example.com`, with the status code 301 to `http://example.com/`.

But if you want to rewrite requests from one directory to another, try this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^folder-1/?([^/].*)?$ folder-2/$1 [L]
```

---

**Edit**   In response to your comment:

```
RewriteCond $0 !=site2/index.php
RewriteRule ^site2/.* site/index.php [L]
```

Comment: AH. As you may have surmised, I did not create this .htaccess file. I am simply trying to edit it so that I can attempt to use url-rerouting in a subfolder of a server.

Comment: I'm not sure if what I am trying to do is rewrite a request from one directory to another. I want all requests outside of /site2/ to remain outside of it, but all requests inside /site2/ to point to /site2/index.php